# (eclipse) difference between import and create project on existing source

Tags: java, eclipse

i usually have to build on top of APIs or other projects. i am not very familiar with eclipse, so what would be the difference between **import project** and **create project on existing source**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Import Project is for projects that you have created either using Eclipse or other compatible IDEs, and that have a project file associated to them.

Meanwhile, create project from existing source, is meant for creating a new project (creating a new project file) when you only have the source code for the project and no associated project files.

While the first option will attempt to import settings such as the runtime you want it to run on, etc. the second will simply go with the default eclipse options.

Comment: thanks. as i also experienced, **create project on existing source** option is the suitable one, since mostly i don't know whether the original author used eclipse or not.

Comment: by ''project file'' do you mean ''build.xml''? or what is the name of that file?

Comment: The project file is a .project file that is created in the root directory of every project you create. Plus, Eclipse will add extra information such as those contained in the .settings folder.